# phase portrait/space of autonomous system of Ordinary Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need help in understanding the statement below.

> Also the direction of the vectors give the direction of the trajectory as t increases so we can show the time dependence of the solution by adding in arrows to the trajectories.

I'm aware that the direction of the vectors in the direction field corresponds to the derivative of the dependent variables. How does this relate to the time dependence of solution?